# What chemical reaction could be used to make copper pennies a vibrant red?

Tags: inorganic-chemistry, transition-metals, metallurgy

I’m an artist working on a piece using pennies to illustrate my drawing and I need my pennies to be red in a certain portion. I’m trying not to use paint and was wondering if there was a way to make them a brownish-red color.

Comment: Note: copper itself is brownish-red. Welcome to our site!

Comment: “The Colouring, Bronzing and Patination of Metals: A Manual for Fine Metalworkers, Sculptors and Designers” by Richard Hughes and Michael Rowe (Thames & Hudson, 1991) is **the** definitive reference. Pages and pages of photographed samples listing experimental conditions for each - chemical, recipe, temperature, duration. Even things like whether you dip in the solution, paint it on, or saturate sawdust in the solution and leave your item in there for a week. Still in print after 28 years, deservedly. Horribly expensive but you will be able to get it second hand.

Comment: @Martin Kochabski I think your comment is informative enough to be an answer! :)

Comment: @MartinKochanski Yes, do put it into an answer.